# Which design pattern is suitable for MVC project development

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4, design-patterns

Please can any one suggest me, which design patter in best for Big MVC pattern,
I had google it, but could not get satisfied answers.
please help, your answer will be very helpfull to me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read the [help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) bout what questions to ask and what not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, you should go for Repository and Unit of Work Patterns.

Please follow below link for more details:

Click [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)!
to check, implementing the **Repository and Unit of Work Patterns in an ASP.NET MVC Application**

Hope! this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Which design pattern is best for MVC? Try MVC!

Comment: David, i am asking about Design pattern , not about architecture.

Comment: Ignore me. Just being flippant!